# Share kindle books with family on android?

Tags: kindle, ebook-management, android

My child has an Android phone. I have created an Amazon household account and created a child profile. I have added books to his profile.

**My question is how can my child read these books on the Android phone?**

Do children need their own Amazon/kindle account?